# SQL Server error when opening the exe that uses the database

Tags: sql-server

I'm not a programmer or anything, I bought a software a couple of years ago and I formatted the computer, but when I called the software company that made the software for me, all their phone numbers aren't working, I think they went out of business or something.

I have the exe and everything, and a SQL Server database `.mdf` and `.ldf`, I attach the database to SQL Server through Management Studio, after I install it, but when I open the exe file I get a SQL Server error I will attach a picture of the error in the question, the software was fine before, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong should I do something else beside just attaching the database, forgive me, I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to programming stuff, can anyone please help me ...

Thank you so much

[this is the error message snapshot](http://s10.postimg.org/fdpak1rop/error1.jpg)

[This is the content of my config file](http://s13.postimg.org/4eojcnnza/configuration.jpg)

and also there is a text file named 1 i don't know if that's relevant or not.

This is the content of that text file

(Data Source=.\SA;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Samar\Documents\DB_Center.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True)

Comment: your software can not make a connection to database there is many possible reason for this for example: 1.connection way and parameters which software uses to communicate with database, 2.you sql-server network configs, 3.allowed authentication mode (windows, SQL or both) 4.MSSQL service, 5...etc, we have to see the software and your DB configs

Comment: Thank you so much for answering me , i'm not really sure what i'm looking for i opened the config file , i'm gonna add the content in my original question , and also does that mean i should change the name of my instance ?

Comment: of course the server/instance names should be same (I mean your existing with which is mentioned in config file)

Comment: Thank u very much , i did change the name and the physical location inside the config file , but still the same error , it's not a software problem cause it was working just fine before , it's all in the attachment of the database i knew it , can you please help , thank you again so much for your help so far

Comment: you have already attached the db so you don't need to "AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Samar\Documents\DB_Center.mdf;" in config file, try with removing it

Comment: also you need to specify the database name in connection string

Comment: Still not working , maybe i'm typing the source , like the instance name wrong , this is a snapshot of my server properties           (http://s16.postimg.org/3jwr798ol/server.png) which is the instance name , forgive me i just have no idea what to do

Comment: ("<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DB_Engine.database.Model1.csdl|res://*/DB_Engine.database.Model1.ssdl|res://*/DB_Engine.database.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS2;AttachDbFilename=F:\Center\DataBase\DB_Center.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup></configuration>")

Comment: That's my configuration file now , what do i need to change exactly , thank you again for your help and patience..

Answer (score 0):

In the same folder as the application, look for a .config file (likely to have the same name as the executable).
In this config file should be settings, one of which might be the pointer to a database (called a connection string), which you will want to change to point to your database you just attached.

The error message would indicate that the instance of SQL Server the application is looking for cannot be found...

Comment: The software may have not any config file.

Comment: Correct, but it would be the first place I'd look. If not, decompiling might be next on the to do list :) We know the software is not finding the instance of SQL, so I don't think it's authentication etc,a different error would be shown.